# What to do/invest with money, graduate from home

Tags: investing, canada

Sorry for the very broad question but I am starting to look ahead. I will be graduating from university and starting a job in the near future making approximately $3000 - $3500 a month (take home). I will have no debt coming out of university and won't have to drive a car.

With this being said I'm assuming I'll be saving around $2500 a month by living at home. What do I do with all this money? Buy an apartment and rent it out? Invest? I live in Canada, Ontario.

Comment: by "living at home" you mean with your parents? How long do you intend to do that? My first goal would be to start saving up for a home for _myself_ rather than a rental property.

Comment: @DStanley Yes with my parents. Don't know an exact time but i'd say at least 3 years for sure.

Answer (score 4):

> I am starting to look ahead.

+1

> Buy an apartment and rent it out?

First you need a down payment!!!  (Preferably 20%.  That'll take time to accumulate.)

> What do I do with all this money?

1. Fully fund your Registered Retirement Savings Plan (up to 15%) in a mix of aggressive and conservative funds.  (Being American, I don't know what the plans offer.)
2. Get your feet under yourself as to what your monthly expenses are like.
3. Track your spending.  (All of it!!!)
4. **Live below your means.**
5. After a few months, make budget, and stick to it.
6. Budgets are not torture chambers designed to restrict your fun.
7. Build an Emergency Fund of 3-4 months worth of expenses.
8. Save the left-over in an on-line bank for a year or so while you settle down, and learn more about adult life and investing.  (Heck, you might find a POSSSLQ -- modernized version of POSSLQ -- that you want to marry and procreate with.)
9. Then decide what medium- and long-term investments you want to put your money in.

(EDIT: these suggestions might sound trite and obvious Common Sense, but Voltaire was right: Common sense is quite rare.)

Comment: I might add that following these steps, plus "avoid debt like the plague" will quickly guarantee your financial freedom for the rest of your life.

Comment: 10. Thank your parents profusely for allowing you to live at home for so little when you could clearly afford to live on your own.